# Add back a luks passphrase to clevis setup

Tags: luks

I have a laptop here that has LUKS setup with clevis to automatically unlock. There previously was a passphrase to unlock it as well, but either I have forgotten it or it was removed.

I'd like to add a passphrase option back because if the TPM policy is ever not satisfied, I will be S.O.L.

But to add a luks passphrase I need either an existing passphrase (which I do not have) or a key file. Presumely clevis creates a keyfile from what is released by the TPM.

How can I add a passphrase to luks using clevis's keyslot as the existing key?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of `clevis-luks-unlock`, which is just a shell script, it looks like it actually has stashed an encrypted passphrase in a jwt in the luks2 header.

I'll copy the source here in a momemt when I'm not on my phone